# Laravel Migration stuck after creating new Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

**My XAMPP**

[image]

**My Phpmyadmin**

[image]

**My Code at .env**

[image]

**My php artisan migrate**

[image]

I always get stuck at there.
I'm using Laravel 5.6, and PHP 7.2.9

It should be noted that this laravel project is a new one, and I don't have any migration except the default migration code.

[image]

Comment: usually it takes long time, maybe you just wait

Comment: Have you try to use docker and docker-compose for this setup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your xampp port mysql is 3306. And your phpmyadmin is 8012. Why it different? can try use 3306 in .env?

Comment: Oh yeah..! thanks a lot..!! I'm currently new to laravel and try to learn about it. I'll note that laravel database target the mysql, while phpmyadmin use apache. :) Really thanks a lot. (For the answer mark, it says that i need to wait for 3 more minutes)

Comment: Btw, should I make it the same? for phpmyadmin and mysql? 'cause my xampp was installed just now, and i got port 80 blocked, so i changed it to 8012

Comment: just suggest, you no need xampp, currently PHP have to do run server without apache, try work with linux or docker it will be helpful for your career or your development stack :)

Answer (score 0):

When I create any Laravel project now, the first thing I do I specify the default string length.

I first open **AppServiceProvider.php** then do as following:

```
    public function boot()
    {
       Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    }
```

So try this and tell me if this solved your problem?

Comment: No, my problem solving is that my DB_PORT value is apache's port, not mysql's port, as Martin states :) And thank you for your response :))